# Twig function not executing?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a Twig function to simply print a message. Is it not able to do this? If anyone can help me find out what is going on, I will be very grateful, I can't find anything on their documentation.

I have this line in my template file.

```
{{ print_twig_message('Hello, from Twig.') }}
```

It's supposed to call this function

```
$this->environment->addFunction(new \Twig_Function('print_twig_message', function ($message) {
    echo $message;
}));
```

But nothing ever gets printed, I've even tried `exit()`.

Comment: Could you please provide a full, runnable piece of code that demonstrates your issue? There is nothing wrong in the code you posted, the issue must lie somewhere else.